# python 'requests' package with proxy not working

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Here are my test code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.ipify.org/'
proxyapi = 'http://ip.11jsq.com/index.php/api/entry?method=proxyServer.generate_api_url&packid=1&fa=0&fetch_key=&qty=1&time=1&pro=&city=&port=1&format=txt&ss=1&css=&dt=1'
proxy = {'http' : 'http://{}'.format(requests.get(proxyapi).text)}
print ('Downloading with fresh proxy.', proxy)
resp = requests.get(url, proxies = proxy_new)
print ('Fresh proxy response status.', resp.status_code)
print (resp.text)
#terminal output
Downloading with fresh proxy. {'http': 'http://49.84.152.176:30311'}
Fresh proxy response status. 200
222.68.154.34#my public ip address
```

with no error message and seems that the requests lib never apply this proxy settings. The proxyapi is valid for I've checked the proxy in my web browser, and by visiting https://api.ipify.org/, it returns the desired proxy server's ip address.

I am using python 3.6.4 and requests 2.18.4.

Comment: You did not define a proxy for `https` just for `http`.

Comment: variable proxy_new is not defined

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, that worked. thanks.

Comment: Hope to be helpful, the proxy dict must be in lower case 'http' or 'https', otherwise the requests lib will use the public ip and no error about the proxy will be thrown.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, thank you, i just wrong typed the variable

Comment: @KlausD. can you explain what happened when visiting a https website with http proxy or vice versa, I googled for it but get no answer.

Comment: Sorry, but how proxies work is not a goid topic for SO.